# .pdf is missing when send as email attachment (Outlook) from Adobe Reader 11.0.06

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pdf, adobe-reader

When I open a PDF file in Internet Explorer and choose to "Send file as email attachment using desktop email" Microsoft Outlook starts and creates a new mail window with the attached file but with no `.pdf` file extension.

How can I resolve this issue? Please help!